# How to prevent the vertical scroll of this div?

Tags: html, css, scroll, xhtml

I am not so into CSS and I have the following problem.

I have the following situation: into a page I have a very large table (that was horizontally truncated because it not entered in the page).

So to solve this issue I put this table into a scrollable div, something like this:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    // Into this div there is my original table
</div>
```

So I have used the **overflow-x: scroll;** property because I want that the content of the div is only horizontally scrollable (not vertically). But the problem is that I obtain this output:

[image]

As you can see the div content result scrollable also vertically and I don't want it. I can't post a fiddle because the inner table is rendered by a tag library.

How can I fix this issue and obtain only the horizzontal scroll? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-y: hidden;` instead `overflow-x: scroll;`?

Comment: Great minds think alike @Imgonzalves - sorry for posting over you in the answers

Comment: @LianeStevenson All it's OK. Also you post your answer almost simultaneously ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;">
    // Into this div there is my original table
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `overflow-y: visible;` should be there by default, there may be something else causing the scrollbar. Look at the `overflow-y` value for the various parent `div`s in Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 2):

make the overflow-y:hidden.

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y:hidden;">
    // Into this div there is my original table
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First give your div `<div style="overflow: auto">` and see. If the scroll on the y-axis still shows, type `<div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden">`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
</div>
```